# How to remove duplicates from a vector whose numbers might be in different positions?

Tags: c++, vector

How do you remove elements from a vector of vectors that are identical to another vector but whose elements are not in the same indices?

For example:

```
std::vector<vector<int>> vectA = {{1,3,4}. {1,2,3}, {3,2,1};
```

I want it so that {3,2,1} is removed from vectA and it becomes:

```
vectA = {{1,3,4}, {1,2,3}}
```

Any idea how to proceed efficiently?

Comment: Can you please fix the definition of `vectA` first? The code example does not work.

Comment: this is python?

Comment: c++. for some reason my edit is literally not saving correctly but the definition of the vector should be:

Comment: std::vector<vector<int>> vectA = {{1,3,4}, {1,2,3}, {3,2,1}};

Comment: This looks more like C++ and not Python.  You need to update your language tags accordingly.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So this is C++ code. Please remove the Python tag. Also, check out the [formatting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for stack overflow.  They explain how to format your question.

Answer (score 3):

- Sort the elements of each vector
- Drop duplicates (this is an easy look-up)

If you need to retain the original element order, then build any correspondence you wish: parallel arrays of vectors (original and sorted), pairs of (unsorted, sorted) vectors, etc.  Drop duplicates based on the sorted ones.

I trust that you can take it from here.

Comment: Oh, perfect... didn't think to sort the elements. Dumb of me.

Comment: No, just briefly ignorant -- which is easily corrected.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the behavior of `std::set`, ie. this solves your problem:

```
set<set<int>> input = {{1,3,4}, {1,2,3}, {3,2,1}};
// input is now {{1,2,3},{1,3,4}}
```

This works because a set is basically equal to a sorted vector with no duplicates.

If you really want to, you can now convert to `std::vector`:

```
vector<vector<int>> nums; 
for(auto & s : input) nums.emplace_back(s.begin(), s.end());
```